# Select with multiple tags

Tags: mysql

I'm wanting to modify the following query so that it requires both tags exist on the current element.  It's essentially requiring that 2 rows exist in `tags_to_content` with the specific ID...

```
SELECT
                content.id,
                content_text.content
            FROM content
            INNER JOIN tags_to_content ON (
                tags_to_content2.tag_id IN (1, 2) AND
                tags_to_content2.content_id = content.id
            )
```

Comment: Same problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15859309/mysql-finding-rows-that-have-multiple-tags-and-the-same-id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual way to solve this is to join for each of the desired tags:

```
SELECT
    content.id,
    content_text.content
FROM content
INNER JOIN tags_to_content t1 ON
    t1.content_id = content.id
INNER JOIN tags_to_content t2 ON
    t2.content_id = content.id
WHERE t1.tag_id = 1
AND t2.tag_id = 2
```

Comment: I could have 4-5 tags, so I'd need an inner join for each of those?  There's no better way to do this?

Comment: yes, even with a dozen or so tags, this is still the most efficient pattern for this kind of query.  inner joins allow the query planner the greatest flexibility for executing your query efficiently.  Other options shouldn't be considered for fewer than dozens or hundreds tags, and generally involve creating temporary tables or more costly subselects.