# search product with their specifications filter

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have a table that contain products with their specifications.i created a sample of data in http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/15575/1 .I want create search form that users can search products by their specifications.for example user search laptop with RAM=2 and VGA=512 or VGA=1.
I wrote a query,but not working.please help me.
this example:
result: 1525,1535,k5,k6
[image]

Comment: What's 'carefree' mean?  If it means, 'no restriction', leave it off - selecting one (or more) company would provide the restriction.  And you're going to want to rethink your UI design - eventually there are going to be even more options, so you're going to want _lists_ of options; which implies dynamic SQL, too.  Oh, I'm not sure that 'VGA' is what you mean - you probably mean 'video memory' or similar, right?  To get additional help on your SQL, please post the relevant portions here.

Comment: Red Filter has given the answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select product 
from my_table  
where (custom = 'Ram' and custom_value = '2') 
    or (custom = 'vga' and custom_value in ('1', '512'))
group by product
having count(distinct custom) = 2
```

**Example:**

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/15575/19

Comment: Can you explain why the count has to equal 2? Is it the amount of where statements?

Comment: We're looking for products that have both the RAM *and* the VGA specification. So we look for products with either specification (see the WHERE clause), and then after the fact count them and make sure we have two distinct ones, meaning it must have matched both. I gave a similar answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8824561/select-rows-with-multiple-tags-is-there-a-better-way

Answer (score 1):

I'm interpreting your request as:
  - Within each of your criteria, you want an `OR` clause.
  - all the criteria are `AND`ed together.

So, for your sample above, you would want:

```
SELECT products.product FROM 
(select distinct product from my_table) as products
where 
   exists (
      select * from my_table where products.product = my_table.product
      and custom='Ram' and custom_value='2')
and exists (
      select * from my_table where products.product = my_table.product
      and custom='vga' and custom_value in('512','1'))
```

Where you start with the unique list of products, and then check each criteria to see if a value exists for that product.

SQL Fiddle here:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/15575/35

Having said that, you should redesign your tables.

You can see from this query what a starting point to a redesign might be.  First, create a table that just lists the unique products.  Then create tables for each of the criteria.  Or expand the table of the unique products to have each of those custom values ('Ram', 'vga', etc.) as columns in the table of unique products.

Answer (score 0):

You want an `or` where you have an `and` I think:

```
SELECT product, count(*) as prod_count FROM my_table  
WHERE (custom='Ram' and custom_value='2') 
or (custom='vga' and custom_value in('512','1'))
group by product
having prod_count = 2
```

Comment: Note, this will produce incorrect results if the same product can have more than one custom type that is the same, e.g., if a PC has two video cards and thus two `vga` custom records. Also, `prod_count` is actually the count of `custom` records per product, not products.

Comment: Ahh, is that where your `distinct` comes in to play? I was wondering about that :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'd recommand you use a different DB structure:

```
CREATE TABLE COMPANY (ID INT, NAME VARCHAR(50), PRIMARY KEY(ID));
CREATE TABLE RAM (ID INT, NAME VARCHAR(50), PRIMARY KEY(ID));
CREATE TABLE CPU (ID INT, NAME VARCHAR(50), PRIMARY KEY(ID));
CREATE TABLE VGA (ID INT, NAME VARCHAR(50), PRIMARY KEY(ID));
```

Then use a relational table to specify products properties:

```
CREATE TABLE PRODUCT_PROPERTIES (
    ID_PRODUCT INT REFERENCES PRODUCT(ID), 
    ID_COMPANY INT REFERENCES COMPANY (ID),     
    ID_RAM INT REFERENCES RAM (ID),    
    ID_CPU INT REFERENCES CPU (ID),    
    ID_VGA INT REFERENCES VGA (ID),
    PRIMARY KEY(ID_PRODUCT)
);
```

Then using simple JOINS and a simple SELECT on your `PRODUCT_PROPERTIES` you can filter your results easily.

Hope this helps..

Comment: Whilst I agree that the thread-starters solution isn't ideal, this method doesn't seem to scale all that well if you decided to add more properties down the line.

Comment: Some would use a relational table for each property but it's useless since it's a one-to-one relationship...