# mysql: finding rows that have multiple tags and the same id

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I'm having an issue figuring the mysql to find links that have two specific 'tags' and the same 'hashid' when doing a JOIN of two tables

Assume my tables look like this:

**Links**

```
md5     url         title   numberofsaves
-----------------------------------------
a0a0    google.com  foo     200
b1b1    yahoo.com   yahoo   100
```

**Tags**

```
 md5    tag
 ---------------
 a0a0   awesome
 a0a0   useful
 a0a0   cool
 b1b1   useful
 b1b1   boring
```

I want to return rows that have tags of BOTH 'useful' and 'awesome'

The current (working/ fast) query for finding links by 1 tag:

```
SELECT links.title, links.numsaves FROM links LEFT JOIN tags ON links.md5=tags.md5 WHERE tags.tag = 'useful' ORDER BY links.numberofsaves DESC LIMIT 20
```

After reading an [article](http://gtowey.blogspot.com/2009/12/how-to-fix-comma-separated-list-of-doom.html) I tried to use the following:

```
SELECT links.title, links.numsaves FROM links LEFT JOIN tags ON links.md5=tags.md5 GROUP BY tags.md5 HAVING SUM(tags.tag='useful') AND SUM(tags.tag='awesome') ORDER BY links.numberofsaves DESC LIMIT 20
```

This *does* work but it is so unbelievably slow as to be unusable.

Anyone know the solution?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The type of problem is called `Relational Division`

```
SELECT  a.md5, 
        a.url,
        a.title
FROM    Links a
        INNER JOIN Tags b
            ON a.md5 = b.md5
WHERE   b.Tag IN ('awesome', 'useful') -- <<== list of desired tags
GROUP   BY a.md5, a.url, a.title
HAVING  COUNT(*) = 2                   -- <<== number of tags defined
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5865b/1)
- [SQL of Relational Division](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/)

OUTPUT

```
╔══════╦════════════╦═══════╗
║ MD5  ║    URL     ║ TITLE ║
╠══════╬════════════╬═══════╣
║ a0a0 ║ google.com ║ foo   ║
╚══════╩════════════╩═══════╝
```

Comment: @JW 웃 , will this cause slow query?